# How to make extendable TextViews in Android TableLayout?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-ndk

I want to create table layout with 2 rows and three columns, 
the first row i want to add 3 TextView s, in the second row i want to add one button spanned on the three columns.

Each text view filled with text from other click action, so, it may contains 100 char and may it contains no char
So, if the first one has chars and the others has not, the fist one should expand to cover all the space, but if two contains texts, the two should expand to fill the empty space

Who can help me?
this my code but this code does not the correct, it divides the table into three equals columns

```
<TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/temps_holder"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/google_adView"
        android:background="@drawable/round"
        android:gravity="right"        
        android:stretchColumns="0" >

        <TableRow>

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/time_temp"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_marginLeft="3dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="3dp"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempText2_TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/tempText1_TextView"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight=".33"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:singleLine="false"
                android:text=""
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:textSize="16sp" />
        </TableRow>

        <TableRow>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/viewMatched_btn"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"                
                android:layout_span="3"
                android:background="@drawable/wood_btn"
                android:onClick="viewResults"
                android:text="@string/viewMatched"
                android:textColor="@color/White"
                android:visibility="invisible" />
        </TableRow>
    </TableLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are after?

```
    <TableRow>

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/viewMatched_btn"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Button"            
            android:onClick="viewResults"               
            android:visibility="visible" />
    </TableRow>
</TableLayout>
```

Change the button property: `android:visibility` to `visible` and add:

`android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: This source code is sub of code from big file, i used xmlns in the orginal file

Comment: Did you tested it with some more than 100 char for each textview ?

Comment: Yes, It will just go to multiple lines.

Comment: The last figure, i want the middle textview expand to fill the blank area to the right of it

Comment: Try using this code: http://pastebin.com/nVPQRB8N I don't think is perfect, but is the best I can do right now. Try tweaking it and see if you can do want you want.